# How to Checkin welcome page with powershell for SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, file, check-in, welcome-page

When i create sharepoint site with powershell:

```
$siteNomenclaturesURL =  "$holidaysSite/Nomenclatures"

New-SPWeb $siteNomenclaturesURL 
-Template "CMSPUBLISHING#0" 
-Name "Noms"  
-UseParentTopNav -Language 1026

$SPWebNomenclatures = Get-SPWeb -Identity $siteNomenclaturesURL
```

**I want to checkin welcome page for this webSite:**

> /Nomenclatures/Pages/default.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$spWeb=Get-SPWeb "SiteURL"

$folder = $spWeb.RootFolder

$pageURL=$folder.WelcomePage

$page = $spWeb.GetFile($pageUrl);

if ($page.CheckedOutBy.UserLogin -eq $spWeb.CurrentUser.UserLogin)
{

$page.CheckIn("Page checked in automatically by PowerShell script")

$page.Publish("Published")

}